# Android WiFi can't get the SSID and BSSID from ScanResult

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, signal-strength

I got this code that i want to scan for the networks and then write it all to the listview. But the problem is that the ssid and bssid doesnt show. Everything else shows but not the ssid.

Also what is the best way to update the listview every second so you can see the signal strenghts actual signal?

```
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.wifi.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    ListView list;
    String wifis[];
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }



    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
            }

            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if u have networkConfig object u can get its ssid

Comment: use `wifiInfo.getSSID();`

Comment: yes i know, but this scans all networks, so when i put "wifiInfo.getSSID();" i only get the 1 wifi name im connected too instead of the name of all networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `SSID` and `BSSID` from the `ScanResult` Object using `wifiScanList.get(i).SSID` and `wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID`.   Then just append it to the other data returned from `toString()`.

See [Documentation Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#SSID).

First, declare your `ArrayAdapter` as an instance variable, and call `setAdapter()` in `onCreate()`:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView list;
ArrayList<String> wifis;
WifiInfo wifiInfo;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    wifis = new ArrayList<String>(); //initialize wifis
    wifis.add("loading...");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis)
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    wifiManager.startScan(); //make sure this is the last call
}
```

Modified `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            //wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()]; //remove this
            wifis.clear(); //add this
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                String ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID; //Get the SSID
                String bssid =  wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID //Get the BSSID
                //use add here:
                wifis.add( ssid + " " + bssid + " " +((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString()) ); //append to the other data
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this
            wifiManager.startScan(); //start a new scan to update values faster

            //ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
             //       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis)
            //list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

This will still only update on each scan result. I don't think it's recommended to update a `ListView` every second, you may want to re-think your approach for showing RSSI levels. You could have an on-click for each SSID, and have a details view with a `TextView` where you update the RSSI every second for the current SSID.

Comment: Thanks, this works :) what is the best way to keep updating the listview for actual values?

Comment: i get this message                                                 "E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity". From the line "  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis);"

Comment: i editted my code, and i got the two declared as instance variables and setcontentview :S

Comment: What call needs to be after the list? cause i still get errors :S

Comment: now its just the loading string all time, cant see any networks anymore

Comment: this works :) thanks so much. Quick question if u got time, how can u decide what the outcome of the scan is? For example i want to take away the timestamp thats inside the scan. How can i do that?

Comment: @Isac You would have to not use `toString()`, and just extract the data you need from the `ScanResult` Object.  Take a look at the documentation in the link.