# How to get current Wifi channel on Android KitKat?

Tags: android

How do you get the current Wifi channel / frequency on Android KitKat devices?

This post talks about it, but it - supposedly - only works for devices with Lollipop (or later OS versions)

[Android wifi getting frequency of the connected Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024449/android-wifi-getting-frequency-of-the-connected-wifi)

Thanks.

Comment: Available in the [ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#frequency) since API1.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, but couldn't find any examples on how to get what i want

Comment: Some simple Googling led me this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29742249/1790644), which does not give you the exact answer you are looking for, but will provide a `ScanResult` object that you should be able to use the above posted call on.

Comment: Looks like an asynchronous call? I'm looking for a way to determine the channel without having to set up a bcast receiver

Comment: `Looks like an asynchronous call` well yeah, its doing a network scan, you should _never_ synchronize on something like that.